# How many drones can I have as a drone tank?

Tags: diep.io

In [diep.io](/questions/tagged/diep.io) you can play as a drone class and you have a limit for drones. What is this limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Necromancer

[image: Necromancer (0 reload) drone limit]

Without any points in Drone Count, a single Necromancer can have a maximum of 22 drones.

For every point spent in Drone Count, you can have 2 more drones. To easily calculate the maximum of Necromancer drones with `r` points in Drone Count, you can solve `22+2r`. With 7 points in Drone Count, you can have a maximum of 36 drones.

## Overseer, Overlord, Manager

[image: Overseer/Overlord/Manager drone limit]

You can have **8** drones as these 3 tanks before reaching the limit.

Unlike Necromancer's drone limit where there is a Drone Count stat replacing Reload, as shown in the above section, you cannot upgrade Drone Count for more drones.

## Overtrapper, Hybrid

[image: Overtrapper/Hybrid drone limit]

You can have **2** drones as either of these tanks before reaching the limit.

You cannot change this limit.

Technically Hybrid isn't a drone tank, but I'm putting it here for completeness.

## Factory

[image: Factory drone limit]

You can have **6** drones as a Factory before reaching the limit.

You cannot change this limit.

Answer (score 1):

### Battleship

[image]

The Battleship can have unlimited drones with a 4-second drone life.