# How can I get a Necromancer drone?

Tags: diep.io

I upgraded to Necromancer but my barrels won't spawn drones. As an Overseer they'd automatically spawn, but even if I click or hold down the spacebar, the drones will not spawn.

Is there a trick to spawning Necromancer drones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to ram a square as a Necromancer to get a drone, since Necromancers use killed squares as their drones, hence their name.

You can use any other way as well as long as you are a Necromancer while killing the square. This includes:

- Shooting a bullet and upgrading into Necromancer before it hits the square
- Using another one of your Necromancer drones
- Time yourself exactly right to make your Overseer drone hit the square just after you upgrade to Necromancer.

As shown in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/303037/145171), you can only repeat this 22 times, with base Drone Count. Any further square kills will be normal square kills and won't give you any drones.

> Necromancer can have a maximum of 22 drones.
>
> For every point spent in Drone Count, you can have 2 more drones. To easily calculate the maximum of Necromancer drones with `r` points in Drone Count, you can solve `22+2r`. With 7 points in Drone Count, you can have a maximum of 36 drones.

Answer (score -1):

A necromancer, eh? Well, you have to smash into a few yellow squares- then, they become your drones. You can use your drones to gather more drones, if you're worried about your health.

And about how far this power goes~ There's a drone limit of 22, with out any points spent on upgrading it, and the limit increases by 2 for every skill point you invest- giving you a max of 36 drones!

Comment: Which stat specifically do you invest in for that?